# Struts2 - Internal action forward gives 404

Tags: struts2

I'm in the process of converting an old Struts1 app to Struts2.

I'm able to get through with some of the actions (such as login,logon,startApplication) successfully - by direct invocation from browser, but internal forwards it ends up with 404 (Not found). For example, when I try to use the browser, I'm able to go to setupMainPageContext.do, however when an existing action performs an internal forward (startApplication.do to setupMainPageContext.do).

Any thoughts?

```
<-- struts.xml -->
    <package name="user" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">    

        <action name="login" class="my.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">jsp/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="successMobile">jsp/login.jsp</result>                 
        </action>
        <action name="logon" class="my.action.LogonAction">
            <result name="success">jsp/sendJsonList.jsp</result>
            <result name="autologin">startApplication.do</result>
        </action>


        <action name="startApplication" class="my.action.controller.StartApplicationAction">
            <result name="success">jsp/startPage.jsp</result>
            <result name="successMobile">setupMainPageContext.do</result>
            <result name="successNoPlugin">setupMainPageContext.do</result>         
        </action>

        <action name="setupMainPageContext" class="my.controller.SetupMainPageContextAction">
            <result name="success">jsp/mainLayout.jsp</result>
        </action>


<!-- Maven Pom -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Forward from one action to the other gives a 404. So, going to startApplication.do, forward to the JSP works fine. But in the successMobile case, I end up with a 404

Comment: How did you invoke that?

Comment: it was a Login variation - if you come thru a mobile device, StartApplicationAction takes you to successMobile result.

Comment: I tried adding a type="chain" attribute in the result element. That gives  **There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [startApplication.do] associated with context path**

Comment: I think I figured out, you cannot have the action extension (.do in my case).

Comment: Action mapping is made differently compared to Struts 1.